# Schedule service to only run at certain times

Tags: windows-server-2003, service, windows-home-server, schedule

I need a way to schedule a service so it can only start between certain hours on a Windows machine (Windows Home Server which is roughly W2k3.)

All help gratefully received!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use windows task scheduler to run `net start service` and `net stop service` at the appropriate times.

Answer (score 3):

Orihara is correct, but here is some additional detail that might help.

You can create .cmd or .bat files that perform the net start and net stop command.  At that point you can use the Windows Task Scheduler (usually under Accessories/System Tools) to schedule the commands start and stop time.  You can also use "at" in the command line to schedule the commands.

Hope that helps.